# Why does echo in Bash modify the content of a independent variable?

Tags: bash, variable, echo, newlines

I have the following code (minimal example).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                                                              
                                                                                                         
echo -ne "# Foo Bar Baz Hello World \r                           "                                       
var=''                                                                                                   
                                                                                                         
function fun {
  # some stuff happening in between                                                                                         
  var='something else'
}

fun

echo $var
```

Surprisingly, the output is:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh
                           something else
```

**Can someone explain why the above echo is able to modify the content of the variable?**

Comment: It was a misconception of how `$(fun)` works, actually.

Comment: You don't seem to use `$(fun)` in your code.

Comment: Sure, not in this minimal example.

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` in the above script does **not** modify the variable `var`. It cannot.
What is happening here:

1. The first `echo` is called, prints a line with `"# Foo Bar Baz Hello World \r"` and immediately overwrites it with the trailing characters after the `\r` (here: white spaces).
2. `var` is set to `''`.
3. function `fun` is created.
4. `fun` is called, `var` is set to `'something else'`
5. Now comes the crucial point: Because `echo -n` does not print a new line character, the output of `var` will overwrite the characters after the trailing characters above until the length of `var` is reached.

Due to this behavior, the content of all three parts of input (`"# Foo Bar Baz Hello World"`, `"                            "` and `'something else'` are echoed on top of each other, resulting in an entire mix-up.

This entangled output is "passed on" by the script (and may lead to nasty side-effects).

To make it clearer:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne "# Foo Bar Baz Hello World             \r  ANYTHING"
var=''

function fun {
  var=D
}

fun

echo $var
```

Output:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh
  ANYTHINGDaz Hello World
```

Thus, we learn the following:

`echo -ne "Something    \r"` can be used in combination with `echo` returning a value if only spaces follow `\r` and the scripts output is trimmed, but only if the string before `\r` has a smaller length than `var`.

=> Avoid.

Answer (score 2):

If the OP is really wondering why a function can modify a variable in the main program, it is to do with scope.  By default all variables are global in scope and can be written to and read from both within and without functions.  To put this another way, functions execute in the same shell as the calling program, not in a subshell.

However, variables can be declared to be local to a function, in which case they are only visible within the function that creates them (and any function it calls), and are destroyed on exit.

When a subshell is created variables are placed in the environment and cannot be altered within the subshell.  If they are overwritten, then it is by creating a variable within that subshell, which is lost on exit.

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                              

var=''                                                                                                   
var2=''                                                                                                   
echo ">$var<>$var2<"
                                                                                                         
function fun {
  # some stuff happening in between                                                                                         
  var='something else'
  local var2='local'
}

fun
echo ">$var<>$var2<"

(
  echo ">$var<"
  var='level'
  echo ">$var<"
)
echo ">$var<"
```

First create two variables and see what they are.
Next create the function and assign "something else" to the global variable and create a local variable containing "local".
Call the function.
Now look at the variables, the global one has been set, but the local one has not.

For contrast, the last section first echos the variable from the environment, sets it and echos it.  However on return from the subshell the change is lost:

```
$ ./X
><><
>something else<><
>something else<
>level<
>something else<
```

Comment: Thank you very much!